# C++, how can I make a dynamic 3D matrix?

Tags: c++

In **C++**, Codeblocks environment, I declared:

```
int m[120][120][120];
```

I know that from `m[0][0][0]` to `m[119][119][119]` I have variables.

Can I make the computer to start declaring memory from positions `m[45][45][45]`?

I hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: Are you commenting your title? :D

Comment: Why would you do that? You can simply declare it `m[120-45][120-45][120-45]` instead.

Comment: I personally don't understand what you expect the computer to do. What do you mean when you say 'declare memory'? Also, I do not see a relation to the 'dynamic' word in your title. Please clarify, maybe with an example.

Comment: You have a string made out of lowercase letters, uppercase letters and digits. Let us say: ABCabcabcacdacde23acd323 and so on. The algorithmic problem is to find how many different sequences of 3 characters are in the string. ABC is a sequence, BCa is another sequence. I want to make it as efficient as possible, in terms of time. My idea was to make a matrix a[][][], and when I read for example ABC, I make a[A][B][C]++. In this way, the ASCII code is taken. The letters start aprox. at 45 and end at 123. But when compiling I get only 50 points out of 100p because of memory usage. That't it.

Comment: Got 70 points now:)) Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need 45..119 just make your matrix 45 smaller in each dimension and convert the values

```
// Very simple example to explain what I meant.
class MyMatrix
{
    public:
        SetValue(int x, int y, int z, float value) { mMatrix[x-45][y-45][z-45] = value; }
    private
        float mMatrix[120-45][120-45][120-45];
}
```

Comment: I think it will work what you said. You're right, thought on it for some minutes! I am going to try to see if I get 100p. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

What you say is basically reserving/allocating some memory at the beginning, and if later on you needed more memory, you want it to be extended.

If that's the case, you'd better use `std::vector`, and pass `45` as the initial capacity. Usually `45` is too small, but if you want to set it anyway, you can do it through `std::vector.reserve(n)` method. It would be something like this:

```
matrix = vector<vector<vector<float> > >();
matrix.reserve(45);
for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = vector<vector<float> >()
    matrix[i].reserve(45);
    for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = vector<float>();
        matrix[i][j].reserve(45);
    }
}
```

You can also achieve the same thing using the *fill* constructor, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I described my problem a little further by commenting the question. Can you please have a look? :)